# angular passing index of currently selected item (in select list)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass through the index of the currently selected item so that I may use it's index to dig deeper into some nested array. Here's what I have so far.

my controller:

```
$scope.scope1Change = function() {

        $scope.array3.length = 0;
        $scope.array4.length = 0;


        $scope.array2 = $scope.array[$scope.scope1].areas;

        angular.forEach($scope.array[$scope.scope1].areas, function(index) {
            angular.forEach(index.sections , function(indx){
                $scope.array3.push(indx);
            });
        });

        angular.forEach($scope.array[$scope.scope1].areas, function(tex) {
            angular.forEach(tex.sections , function(texi){

                angular.forEach(texi.lessons , function(texa){

                    $scope.array4.push(texa);

                });
            });
        });


    };
```

html:

```
                    <select class="selectLevel1" ng-model="scope2"  ng-change='scope2Change()' 
                                ng-options='area.name for area in array2 track by area.id' >
                                </select>


                    <select class="selectLevel2" ng-model="scope3" ng-change='scope3Change()' 
                            ng-options='obj.name for obj in array3 track by obj.id' >
                    </select>
```

So I want the index of the currently selected item so that it knows which array to look into to then populate the select list below it (and a few more below, I'm just trying to get this to work at first). If I hard code a value in the brackets like $scope.array[0], it works fine, but I'm trying to get it work dynamically. [$scope.scope1] returns the full object, when I'm just lookin for its index as an number value. Any way to accomplish this in angular? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

$scope.array[$scope.array.indexOf($scope.scope1)]